# Angular ui-router resolve is calling function that returns object properly, but still ends up getting undefined. Why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a custom function that properly returns a cache object of user details. Additionally, the function checks to see if the cache is empty beforehand and makes an API call to retrieve the appropriate data if necessary. However, when I call this function from the angular ui-router resolve it still ends up getting undefined. I don't understand... because all my console printed statements within the custom function show that the correct object is being returned.

```
function getCache(UserService) {
    if(cacheIsEmpty) {
        UserService.getProfile().then(function (profile) {
            // check to see profile returned correctly
            console.dir(profile);

            // set cache using returned profile
            ...

            // create object loaded from cache
            var cacheObj = {
                firstName: // get from cache
                lastName:  // get from cache
                ...
            }

            // check if my object is correctly created
            console.log(cacheObj):

            // now return this correctly created object
            return cacheObj;

        });

    } else {

        // the following creates object directly from cache
        // since it is NOT empty and can be used
        var cacheObj = {
            firstName: // get from cache
            lastName:  // get from cache
            ...
        }

        // print to check object is correct
        console.dir(cacheObj);

        // now return it
        return cacheObj;
    }

}
```

And in the resolve, a call to this function returns as defined... despite the fact that the object is correctly being returned from the object.

```
...
resolve: {
    cacheObj: function(UserService) {

        // call the getCache function
        var returnedUserObject = getCache(UserService);

        // printing the object here shows that it is undefined
        console.log(returnedUserObject);

        // return the object to the controller
        return returnedUserObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: The return inside `then()` does not return to outer function. When `cacheIsEmpty` is true...nothing gets returned from `getCache()`

Comment: @charlietfl Oh wow! That makes sense. Thanks...  but then... how do I handle this situation properly... because I need to ensure that the resolve waits for the object to return from the API call... otherwise just an empty object will be returned.

Comment: If a promise is returned in one case...a promise has to be returned in other case also. Just like @Pankaj is trying to show you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return a promise from `getCache` function, so that `resolve` recognise that till promise gets resolved I need to wait. Here you haven't returned a promise from `if(cacheIsEmpty)` method where you are making `UserService.getProfile` method call. Though returning data from promise from `.then` function doesn't mean you are returning promise.

**Code**

```
function getCache(UserService) {
    //return promise from both the places, if & else
    if(cacheIsEmpty) {
        //return promise here
        return UserService.getProfile().then(function (profile) {
            // check to see profile returned correctly
            console.dir(profile);

            // set cache using returned profile
            ...

            // create object loaded from cache
            var cacheObj = {
               firstName: // get from cache
               lastName:  // get from cache
               ...
            }
            //return cacheObj from here when promise resolved
            return cacheObj;
        });
    } else {
        //create cached cacheObj from cache and return it
        return $q.resolve(cacheObj)
    }
}
```

**Resolve**

```
resolve: {
    cacheObj: function(UserService) {
        return getCache(UserService);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. The problem I am having is NOT that the resolve is not waiting for the profile API. Honestly, I have already implemented something similar to what you have suggested. The only reason I didn't provide all my code is because the problem is within the first `if` statement and how when the object is returned... it ends up being undefined within the resolve.

Comment: so basically the `cacheObj` that I am creating and returning is turning up as undefined even AFTER the resolve waits for its return.

Comment: @Grateful No way. May I know have you returned `cacheObj` from `UserService.getProfile()` .then function, Its needed there

Comment: Actually yes. It's my fault I didn't show this in the code above. Kindly let me update it to show more accurately what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: @Grateful No man, you haven't return `UserService.getProfile()` promise object.. please check my answer

Comment: I have updated my code to more accurately reflect my situation.

Comment: @Grateful I checked it, you missed to return promise,,please check

Comment: Oh.. I see... let me try that out! Thanks again.

Comment: OH AMAZING!! Thanks. It works... although, the explanation from @charlietfl helped me to better understand your answer. Thank you both.

Comment: @Grateful though my comment inside the code had already explained that part.. but still I'll update my answer